# Wrapping a button around a scrolling pane

Tags: jquery, css

I have a content pane area that is a list, which slides to another area on click. So second area starts out hidden. I have an image button that I want to "wrap" on the edge of the pane, like the image here. But I can only make it work without having overflow set to hidden. But then of course both panes show at once. Is there a way to do this? Thanks.
[alt text http://img.skitch.com/20100701-xmeha5rhwa9hhw38j61b7t5j6.png](http://img.skitch.com/20100701-xmeha5rhwa9hhw38j61b7t5j6.png)

Comment: It would help if you had a demo set up so we could help you better.

Comment: Yeah sorry its all just pieces locally right now :(

Comment: Can you explain this with more details using the imagery... and perhaps provide more images the "list", what you click to show the list, and what you want to show up once you do click?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a new div with an absolute positioning for the button to sit in then position it over the edge of the slider that way?